# Yii Creating a Create & Update MVC with unrelated tables

Tags: php, activerecord, yii

So I have schemca very similiar to:

```
users
--------------
userid, name, password, email 

userinroles 
--------------
pk, userid, roleid

roles
-----------
roleid, level, description
```

As you can see the roles table is related to the users via the userinroles table, this is so a user can have edit rights within various groups and have different levels of access for different things. For example they might need to be a page editor while having a super admin rights on a module.

The problem is when I'm updating or creating a record I don't know how to list the roles such that you can check a box to what role they should have and insert that into the userinroles table.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Model:

```
Yii::import('application.models._base.BaseUser');
class User extends BaseUser
{
    public static function model($className=__CLASS__) {
        return parent::model($className);
    }
        public function rules() {
        return array(
                array('username, password, email', 'required'),
                array('isActive, isDeleted, isLocked', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
                array('username', 'length', 'max'=>50),
                // Throws error if user name is not unique 
                array('username', 'unique', 'attributeName'=> 'username', 'caseSensitive' => 'false'),
                array('password', 'length', 'max'=>255),
                array('email, organization, position', 'length', 'max'=>100),
                array('salt', 'length', 'max'=>32),
                array('organization, position, salt, isActive, isDeleted, isLocked', 'default', 'setOnEmpty' => true, 'value' => null),
                array('userid, username, password, email, organization, position, salt, isActive, isDeleted, isLocked', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
        );
    }
    public function relations() {
        return array(
            'toolaccesses' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Toolaccess', 'userID'),
            'usergalleries' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Usergallery', 'userid'),
            'userinroles' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Userinroles', 'userid'),
                        'tools' =>array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Tool', 'toolid'),
        );
    }        
}
```

Controller:

```
class UserController extends GxController {


    public function actionView($id) {
        $this->render('view', array(
            'model' => $this->loadModel($id, 'User'),
        ));
    }

    public function actionCreate() {
        $model = new User;


        if (isset($_POST['User'])) {
            $model->setAttributes($_POST['User']);

                        // salting the user's password before we insert
                        $model->password = md5(Yii::app()->params["salt"] . $model->password);

            if ($model->save()) {
                if (Yii::app()->getRequest()->getIsAjaxRequest())
                    Yii::app()->end();
                else
                    $this->redirect(array('view', 'id' => $model->userid));
            }
        }

        $this->render('create', array( 'model' => $model));
    }

    public function actionUpdate($id) {
        $model = $this->loadModel($id, 'User');

        if (isset($_POST['User'])) {
                    // testing if we need to salt the password. 
                    if(strcmp($_POST['User']['password'], $model->password)!=0)
                    { // passwords passed in are not the same. We need to now modify the post password
                        $_POST['User']['password'] = md5(Yii::app()->params["salt"] . $_POST['User']['password']);
                    }
                    $model->setAttributes($_POST['User']);
                    if ($model->save()) {
                            $this->redirect(array('view', 'id' => $model->userid));
                    }
        }

        $this->render('update', array(
                'model' => $model,
                ));
    }

    public function actionDelete($id) {
            // prevent the deletion of the super user, who has the ID 1. 
            // This is sort of like a Unix "root" user or a Window's Administrator
            if($id == 1)
            {
                throw new CHttpException(400, Yii::t('app', 'You cannot delete the super admin.'));
            }
            else 
            {
        if (Yii::app()->getRequest()->getIsPostRequest()) {
            $this->loadModel($id, 'User')->delete();

            if (!Yii::app()->getRequest()->getIsAjaxRequest())
                $this->redirect(array('admin'));
        } else
            throw new CHttpException(400, Yii::t('app', 'Your request is invalid.'));
            }
    }

    public function actionIndex() {
        $dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('User');
        $this->render('index', array(
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ));
    }

    public function actionAdmin() {
        $model = new User('search');
        $model->unsetAttributes();

        if (isset($_GET['User']))
            $model->setAttributes($_GET['User']);

        $this->render('admin', array(
            'model' => $model,
        ));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I think you should use Many-Many relation between users and roles table -

```
    public function relations() {
    return array(
        'toolaccesses' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Toolaccess', 'userID'),
        'usergalleries' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Usergallery', 'userid'),
        'roles' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Roles', 'userinroles(userid, roleid)'),
        'tools' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Tool', 'toolid'),
    );
```

After that, you will able to get roles for users with `$user->roles`. About some actions with roles, related to concrete user: i use [this extension](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/advancedrelationsbehavior/) to save many-many relations. Sorry if i understood you wrong.